# How to convert (managed to unmanaged) array<System::Byte ^> to byte*?

Tags: c++-cli

I need help to make such conversion:

```
byte* bytes = Battle::Storm::GetBytes(0);
```

Now I get the error:

> Error  3   error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'cli::array ^' to 'byte *'

How can I do this?

Comment: Do you want to convert it to native `byte (unsigned char)` pointer or managed byte array which is `array<byte>^` ?

Comment: I want to convert it to native byte or char*

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From the error message I understand that `Battle::Storm::GetBytes(0);` returns a multi dimensional array, which is in the form of `cli::array<Byte,dimension> ^`

To convert it to native `unsigned char*`

```
array<Byte,N> ^ byteMultiArray = Battle::Storm::GetBytes(0);
pin_ptr<unsigned char> array_pin = &byteArray[0, ... ,Nth 0]; 
unsigned char * nativeArray = array_pin;
```

Here the number N is the dimension of the array.

```
//for N = 2  
pin_ptr<unsigned char> array_pin = &byteArray[0,0];
//for N = 4  
pin_ptr<unsigned char> array_pin = &byteArray[0,0,0,0];
```

Comment: with N 1 it works :) Thank you, I was just so confused with C++CLI syntax.

Answer (score 11):

You can use pin_ptr<> to get unmanaged array

```
array<Byte>^ arr =  gcnew array<Byte>(100) ;
pin_ptr<unsigned char> pUnmanagedArr = &arr[0];
```

Comment: more correct is : array<System::Byte ^> ^ arr =  Battle::Storm::GetBytes(0); but I'm getting error : Error 3 error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'cli::array<Type,dimension> ^' to 'cli::array<Type> ^' and on next line: Error 4 error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'cli::interior_ptr<Type>' to 'cli::pin_ptr<Type>'

Comment: @nCdy: What is the exact return type of `Battle::Storm::GetBytes(0)` ?

Comment: The answer properly used Byte, not Byte^.

Comment: @nCdy: Yes it is byte array but, a multidimensional one. What is the dimension?

Comment: just clr byte array. there is no dimension in it, but I can check size with .Length sure.

Comment: I guess that's how C++CLI see clr arrays. I'm importing it from clr library (not c++cli) so I can import array size with it too, for compatibility. But if I set some value there (alike : array<System::Byte^,5> ^ byteArray = Battle::Storm::GetBytes(0);) I will get : Error 3 error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'cli::array<Type,dimension> ^' to 'cli::array<Type,dimension> ^'

Comment: @nCdy: as @Hans said, use `Byte`, not `Byte^`. `array<System::Byte,5>^ byteArray = Battle::Storm::GetBytes(0);`

Comment: same with Byte : Error 3 error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'cli::array<Type,dimension> ^' to 'cli::array<Type,dimension> ^'

Comment: @nCdy: Because now the dimension 5 must be wrong. Please read the manual of `Battle::Storm::GetBytes()`, or look at the source code.

Comment: yes, you are right, it works with array<System::Byte,1> ^ byteArray = Battle::Storm::GetBytes(0);